# How to attach a trust policy to a IAM role using CDK

Tags: typescript, amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, aws-cdk

```
{
    "Version": "2008-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": [
                    "arn:aws:iam::1234:role/role1",
                    "arn:aws:iam::1235:role/role2",
                    "arn:aws:iam::1236:role/role3",
                    "arn:aws:iam::1237:role/role4"
                ]
            },
            "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
        }
    ]
}
```

I have tried writing code using Arnprinciple. But I think it is accepting only one role. But I want to attach all 4/multiple roles at a time. Please help me.

Comment: Can you show your code?

Comment: Use `assumedBy` property in CDK.

Comment: I think you are confusing yourself with the `Principal` and `Resource`. The trust policy defines which principals can assume this _role_ (to which you are adding the trust policy).  Trust policy has the Principal element, but no Resource element. This is because the resource is the IAM role itself. The Principal element indicates which other principals can assume the IAM role.

Answer (score 2):

When you create the iam role via cdk you can specify the assumedBy field which sets the trust policy

```
new iam.Role(this, 'CyclotronGlueJobRole', {
            roleName: glueJobRoleName,
            assumedBy: new CompositePrincipal(
                new iam.ServicePrincipal('glue.amazonaws.com'),
                iam.Role.fromRoleName(this, "reloaded-glue-role", glueJobRoleName),
                ...
            ) ,
            inlinePolicies: {
...
```